# Scala - how to convert date to integer

Tags: scala

What is the Scala code to display date as an integer?
For example, the date of today will be shown in integer as:

```
20150922
```

Comment: Which date library are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Joda-Time

Similar to what Reactormonk said, I would recommend [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and its [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class. But you don't want `getMillis()`.  You want to use the [formatting string](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) `yyyyMMdd` as follows:

```
new DateTime().toString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Comment: But that's a string, not an integer, right? The OP asked for an integer.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what he needs, since he didn't format it as `Integer`.  If an actual `Integer` is needed, that's just a question of `Integer.valueOf(myString)`, where `myString` is replaced with the code shown above.  If OP requests, I'll update my answer based on that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use joda-time, then you can call `new DateTime().getMillis()`.

Comment: @ZhongBot "Constructs an instance set to the current system millisecond time using ISOChronology in the default time zone."

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers so far seem to cover your question about how to obtain the current date as an *integer*. This answer also only uses standard Java SE APIs, no third-party libraries.

```
val now = java.time.LocalDate.now

val dateAsInt = now.getYear * 10000 + now.getMonthValue * 100 + now.getDayOfMonth
// => dateAsInt: Int = 20150922
```

Comment: I might mention that by virtue of using scala (as the tag suggests), OP is already using a library on top of java.

Comment: Technically speaking, from the point of view of Scala, Java SE is a third-party library … however, at least until the long talked about but never materialized native LLVM compiler or the abandoned .NET compiler are finished or Scala.JS takes off, I think we can safely assume that Java SE libraries (or at least the subset which also exists on Android) are available in any and all Scala programs, even though the Scala Language Specification only guarantees existence of the *Scala* standard library. It's kind of strange with these platform-hosted languages.

Comment: Very true! I'm not holding my breath, though - I can't see Scala giving up the usefulness of full access to all the JVM libraries any time soon!

Comment: Right. Me neither. On the other hand, I *can* see myself gladly avoid C in favor of Scala even without the library ecosystem for native code ;-) If suddenly someone were to re-implement the underlying infrastructure in Scala and come up with a pure-Scala implementation of the standard library (or even the runtime system as a whole, GC, JIT and all), I'd be happy to by them a beer. Or two. Or ten.

Comment: I'm following soong's suggestion by doing
new DateTime().toString("yyyyMMdd").toInt

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by soong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32724210/642706) and the [Answer by Jörg W Mittag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32725661/642706) are both good. But let's go a couple steps better.

I do not know Scala syntax, but here is code using Java syntax with the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

## Time Zone

Time zone is crucial in determining a date. A new day dawns earlier in Paris than in Montréal, for example.

When omitting the time zone, you are implicitly relying on the JVM’s current default time zone. That makes your code less than obvious as to your intentions. And the default may vary by machine or by sysadmin. Worse, the default time zone can be changed during runtime at any moment by any code in any thread of any app running within the JVM.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );
```

## Formatters

The java.time framework has a predefined format, [DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE), that we need for this purpose.

```
String s = zdt.format( DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE );  // Ex: '20111203'
Integer i = Integer.valueOf( s );
```

I certainly do not recommend doing so, but you *could* string this together in a one-liner.

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf( ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).format( DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ) );
```